# Can't load two characters and print, it just prints one - MIPS

Tags: mips

so the problem is, I have a message that I get from input, then I want it to search for the vowels, and when it finds them it's supposed to add the next consonant. Ex: Bruno - Bruvnop ; Banana - Babnabnab ; a - ab ; e - ef ; i - ij ; o - op ; u - v .
But when I do it, deletes the char after because I save it with the consonant, so I tried to save the char before writing over it to print after but It doesn't work. Could you help me please?

```
 .text
.globl  main

main:
# display prompt
li      $v0, 4
la      $a0, prompt
syscall
# accept input string
li      $v0, 8
la      $a0, str
li      $a1, 82
syscall

li      $t1, 0          # initiate index
li      $t3, 0          # vowel count

poploop:
lb $t0 str($t1)

# check if vowel
li      $t2, 'a'       # a
beq     $t0, $t2, TESTEa
JA:
li      $t2, 'e'       # e
beq     $t0, $t2, TESTEe
JE:
li      $t2, 'i'       # i
beq     $t0, $t2, TESTEi
JI:
li      $t2, 'o'       # o
beq     $t0, $t2, TESTEo
JO:
li      $t2, 'u'       # u
beq     $t0, $t2, TESTEu
JU:

# if not a vowel, store it at current index in string less vowel count

sb $t0, str($t1)
j next
nop

TESTEa: # if vowel, inc count
       (...)
TESTEe:
       (...)
TESTEi:
       (...)
TESTEo:
       (...)
TESTEu:               #They do all the same basically
sb $t2, str($t1)
addi $t1, $t1, 1
lb $t2 str($t1)
move $t2, $a1
li $t0, 'v'
sb $t0, str($t1)
addi $t1, $t1, 1
sb $t2, str($t1)
j JU
next:
addi $t1, $t1, 1

beqz $t0, done       # once we reach null char, finish
nop
j poploop
nop

done:   
li $v0, 4
la $a0, str
syscall
li $v0, 10         # exit program
syscall
nop

.data
 str: .space 82
 prompt: .asciiz "Input a string:\n"
```